# Making multiple instances of the same GUI objects in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm building a GUI in Qt which will require a number of sections to be duplicated, rather than physically copying and pasting each part, I would much prefer a method of using objects / sub classes so that I only need to design it once and make multiple instances of it. It would simplify the development process as I would only need to make changes once.

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I once created an application which would open tabs for files with quite some controls on them. I found that QT eats memory quite greedily. I finally rewrote it because as only one tab widget can be visible at the time, I found it much better to fake it, have only one and just change the data (state of the controls) within that widget creating the illusion of switching widgets.

I don't know if that helps. As to subclassing, well you can just subclass and instantiate your qt classes like any other c++ classes.

Could you be a bit more specific on what doesn't work?

Comment: I currently have a GUI that works for 1 set of controls, and I need to implement it to add an additional channel with exactly the same controls. Subclasing would be simple if I was writing the GUI by hand, however, i'm using the designer as it is easier and allows for a nicer look. The issue is I cant see a simple way to provide a sub-section that would allow for duplication of controls within the designer framework.
As for memory usage, its not really an issue as the machine has 12GB of ram and it will pretty much only be running my software.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't have the designer at hand to have a look. Have a look a the files it generates though, normally you can set names for the classes in the designer. I think you can also group controls. If all else fails you might have a look at QtQuick. Personally I like it better than the old style gui. It has good integretion with the code, but it has a bit of a learning curve. Expect a few days of study if you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass QWidget or QFrame and have it display all the controls that need to be repeated. That way you can just make a few of you subclasses instead of copying and pasting.

```
 class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
     public: 
     explicit MyWidget( QWidget* parent = 0)
     //Member functions
     private:
     QLablel* label;
     QTextField* text;
     //More ui components        
}

MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   label = new QLabel(this);
   text = new QTextField(this)
}
```

From designer if you choose to start with a QWidget instead of QMainWindow then the widget can be added to other widgets or forms. This can be done supposedly by importing the widget back into designer, but I have never gotten that to work. I usually have a placeholder of the same size that I use for design mode, then swap it out when the form with my custom one when the form is populated.